# how can i store only pdf file or filename from folder containing another files with different extensions (.doc, .txt, .html) in variable using python?

Tags: python

Let consider a folders(Mandar and html) on your desktop. Now paste any pdf file and named it 'dell' in 'html' folder and create demo.py file in 'Mandar' folder. Now create some txt files(2-4) as your wish so that 'html' folder contains some txt files and only one pdf file.

```py
import os

import PyPDF2  # install via 'pip install PyPDF2'

# Put location of your pdf file i.e. dell.pdf in 'location' variable
location = "C:/Users/Desktop/html/"  
n = "dell.pdf"
path = os.path.join(location, n)

reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(path)
pages = len(reader.pages)

print(f"The no. of pages in {n} is {pages}.")
```

Now run program and you see that
''The no. of pages in dell.pdf is NUM.'' //NUM is no. of pages of your pdf

Now let consider 'html' folder always contain only one pdf file with any name maybe dell, maybe ecc, maybe any name. I want that variable 'n' stores this one pdf file in itself as input so that the program will run and display same result with different pdf file name and Num.

Answer (score 1):

Give `glob` in the standard library a shot. It'll get you a list of all the matching PDF files in that directory.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
...

import glob

Location='C:/Users/Desktop/html/'
candidates = glob.glob(os.path.join(Location, '*.pdf'))
if len(candidates) == 0:
    raise Exception('No PDFs found')

File=open(candidates[0],'rb')

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for globbing. You can do that with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(location)
pdf_files = root.glob("*.pdf")
```